# Probability distribution for day of the year

Tags: distributions, discrete-data, discrete-time

"Day of the year" is an integer from 1 to 365, indicating the day within the year. I'd like to model the day of the year that a particular event occurs. The event must occur between day 100 and day 200 and the distribution is possibly bell-shaped. What distributions have been used for this?

My first idea in a problem like this is to use the normal distribution. However, this is a discrete variable, and I'd like the distribution to be discrete as well.

Binomial distribution comes to mind. However, I am not sure if the logic of the Binomial distribution applies to this problem. I am not dealing with the number of successes. At the very least, I think I need a generalization of the Binomial distribution in which I can specify both the lower and the upper bounds, the mean and the variance. Does such a generalization exist and can you point me to a reference?

I appreciate any references or pointers to modeling the day of the year.

Comment: You could model the exact instant at which the event occurs in a span of 100 days as a Normal distribution centered at the 50 day mark, and then discretize it by taking 100 integrals of the distribution over partial ranges, where each range is a day. Then divide each probability value by the sum of probability values to normalize it (because the Normal distribution extends infinitely, not through 100 days). Of course, "integrating" simply  means invoking the CDF, which is readily available (as an approximation) in most languages.

Comment: The von Mises distribution (discretisized in the same way) may be more appropriate in general.

Comment: @Jessica How do you now that the event "must" occur (with probability 1) between day 100 and 200?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binomial with N=100 will work as follows:
$$\Pr(X = k)={100\choose k-100}p^{k-100}(1-p)^{n-k+100}$$

For any $k\in[100,200]$ and $p\in(0,1)$ this will produce your bell shaped distribution.

Comment: This fixes the variance at $100p(1-p)$ which may not be desirable.